# jscrollpane continuous scroll for custom arrow buttons doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

I am trying to get my custom scroll buttons to scroll continuously on mousedown.
(instead of scroll on click, which by the way worked fine)
I found this great example (see link and code below), however, for my page, the script works in Firefox, but not in Safari. The example page **does** work in Safari though...  Does anyone know what the problem could be?

http://jsfiddle.net/WzNM4/6/

```
$(function()
{
    var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
    $('#scroll-up').bind(
        'mousedown',
        function()
        {
            var interval = setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    api.scrollByY(-5);
                },
                100
            );
            $(window).bind(
                'mouseup.jspExample',
                function()
                {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $(document).unbind('.jspExample');
                }
            );
        }
    );
    $('#scroll-down').bind(
        'mousedown',
        function()
        {
            var interval = setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    api.scrollByY(5);
                },
                100
            );
            $(window).bind(
                'mouseup.jspExample',
                function()
                {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    $(document).unbind('.jspExample');
                }
            );
        }
    );
});​
```